# Introducir Hora:Minutos en Java

Tags: java

Quiero pasar un `String` (ej: 15:30) a `int`, pero todo lo que estoy actualmente intentando es erróneo:

```
    System.out.println("Hora y minutos");

    String HoraMinutos = entrada.next();

    int hourMinuts = Integer.parseInt(HoraMinutos);

    System.out.println(hourMinuts);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Quieres separar esa cadena en horas y minutos creando dos enteros: `15` y `30` o quieres crear un valor así `1530`, o qué quieres en sí? Pon un ejemplo del resultado esperado. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida. Lo que quiero es introducir la hora en String y que se pase a integer, como bien tú dices. Se podría hacer o debería introducir horas por un lado y minutos por otro?

Comment: ¿Introducir la hora en String donde? ¿Es para agregarla a algún objeto del tipo fecha? Por favor sé más claro que no se logra entender lo que quieres hacer realmente. ¿Quieres dos valores por separado, quieres un solo valor?

Comment: Te recomiendo completar el [tour] y entender qué es un [mcve]. Cuanto más fácil nos pongas el ayudarte, más probable será que obtengas una solución/explicación que sirva.

Answer (score 3):

Una variable int solo puede almacenar un valor. Parece que necesitas dos ints, uno para la hora y otro para los minutos.

Existe una función para cadenas llamada "split" que puedes usar para extraer los fragmentos de la cadena horaMinutos. También debes controlar el formato de entrada para que siempre sea "NN:NN" o tendras problemas de conversión.

Para extraer los fragmentos de la cadena usa:

`String[] fragmentos = "15:30".split(":");`

y para obtener la hora y los minutos puedes usar:

`int hora = Integer.parseInt(fragmentos[0]);`

`int minutos = Integer.parseInt(fragmentos[1]);`

Una vez que empieces a dominar más el lenguaje, te recomiendo que leas acerca de manejo de fechas y horas en Java en el Time API, te hará la vida más fácil para tareas más complejas.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes requerir que el formato introducido por el usuario sea `HH:mm`  y con este valor usar el método [.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) usando ":" como separador para obtener un arreglo con 2 elementos, la hora y los minutos, en este caso para convertir estos valores a int usa `Integer.parse(...)`.

Ejemplo:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);  
     System.out.println("Introduzca Hora y minutos en formato HH:mm"); 
     String HoraMinutos = entrada.next();

     String[] HoraMinArray = HoraMinutos.split(":");

     //Obtiene los valores enteros.
     int valorHora = Integer.parseInt(HoraMinArray[0]); //Hora
     int valorMinutos = Integer.parseInt(HoraMinArray[1]); // Minutos.

    System.out.println("Hora: " + valorHora);
    System.out.println("Minutos: " + valorMinutos);
```

---

```
Introduzca Hora y minutos en formato HH:mm
15:30
```

Salida:

```
Hora: 15
Minutos: 30
```